# multiple number of inputs to a function , specifically itertools.product()

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, python-itertools

i am trying to write a code that needs itertools.product to generate the output from a multiple number of lists , or even variable numbers , for example my inputs will be read from a list as :

```
a=[[[0,1],[2,3]],[[4,5],[6,7]]]
```

for this example it would be easy to write down :

```
itertools.product(a[0],a[1])
```

but as the list may increase in size and code may get pretty large and messy i can not use a code like this :

```
itertools.product(a[0],a[1],a[2],...)
```

what is a clean and efficient alternative way to do this?
i know it is not a function specific question , but a more general question about python itself and functions but i couldn't find any help about the existing functions, if anyone would point me in the right direction i'll be grateful.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `*` to unpack the input list

```
>>> list(itertools.product(*a))
[([0, 1], [4, 5]), ([0, 1], [6, 7]), ([2, 3], [4, 5]), ([2, 3], [6, 7])]
```

Comment: thanks , but this won't solve my problem . the function will not accept a list as input , i want to input multiple lists to the function

Comment: ok, but that will definitely be the list of list, which will work fine I believe

Comment: i'm not quite sure but i think passing a function two lists is different than passing it one list of lists

Comment: ok if you have 2 list `a` and `b`, then you can pass it as `c = [a, b]` and use `list(itertools.product(*c))`

Comment: now that works, thanks , sorry i didn't understand your answer fully at the first. you rock !!!